# Parse Pandas Column to date from string with dashes

Tags: date, datetime, pandas, casting, date-format

Trying to parse pandas columns `df['day']` into datetime type. Values are current written as strings, such as: `2016-9-1`. This corresponds to Year-Month-Day.

I'm following the formatting from this page:
http://strftime.org/

I initially tried to use

```
pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

but got the error

```
ValueError: time data 'day' does match format specified
```

I figured the problem was that day and month weren't zero, padded, so changed it to:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format="%Y-%-m-%-d")
```

I'm using `%-m` and `%-d`, since both correspond to non-zero-padded (decimal) numbers.

Getting different error:

```
ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%-m-%-d'
```

Shouldn't I be following the formatting convention from http://strftime.org/, am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need remove `-` in parameter `format`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':['2016-9-1']})
print (df)
        day
0  2016-9-1

print (pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format="%Y-%m-%d"))
0   2016-09-01
Name: day, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

EDIT:

So it looks like some bad data, so you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':['2016-9-1', '2016-12-0']})
print (df)
         day
0   2016-9-1
1  2016-12-0

#check problematic values
print (df[pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format="%Y-%m-%d", errors='coerce').isnull()])
         day
1  2016-12-0

#convert problematic values to NaT
print (pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format="%Y-%m-%d", errors='coerce'))
0   2016-09-01
1          NaT
Name: day, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: It weird, when I run your code by itself, I get same the same output as you. However, when I run on entire dataframe, I get `ValueError: time data 'day' does match format specified`

Comment: Rargh. Your assessment was spot on, it was bad data. I can't believe how much time I wasted not checking this.